# Struggling with setting the colour of my panels at design time

Tags: delphi-2010

For some reason my panels change colour to the colour of the form no matter what I do. Should I edit this and add a picture of my object inspector or could someone maybe list the possible reasons for this happening? I have checked a few forms (including stack exchange) and havent found anything helpful. I have tried disabling every option involving a child component getting settings from its parent but nothing has worked. Sorry if this question doesn't fit.

Comment: Windows themes mean that the system decides the colours and override your settings. Disable themes if you want to retain control. Or paint the panels yourself.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thanks I forgot about themes, that fixed my problem.